# Is it possible to make this Xpath shorter?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

We develop extensions for Chrome, Firefox and Safari and we test our Chrome and Firefox extensions with Selenium. We have a specific element which can be either span or div (depends on the version of our extension), and we need to validate it with Selenium. The code looks like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver=self.driver, timeout=30).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='top-icon'] | //div[@id='top-icon']")))
self.assertEqual(first=1, second=len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath="//span[@id='top-icon'] | //div[@id='top-icon']")))
```

I would like to know if there is a way to write the xpath shorter (without writing the id twice), but not try to find any element (only span or div).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
//*[self::span|self::div][@id='top-icon']
```

Answer (score 0):

To make an element-agnostic expression, use a `*` in place of `div` or `span`:

```
//*[@id='top-icon']
```

Or, just use a `By.ID` locator:

```
(By.ID, "top-icon")
```

Comment: I don't want to approve any element, only span or div.